# Python List / Index Query

Tags: python, list

I am asking a user to enter a number, in which I want to print the item held at that index point in the list..

This is the code i currently have:

```
List = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

print "The list has the following", len(List), "list:", List

new_item = raw_input("Which item would you like to add? ")
List.append(new_item)
print "The list has the following", len(List), "items:", List

Number = raw_input ("Please select a number: ")
```

Comment: By asking the user to enter a number.... i want the item in that index to be displayed.. e.g. if the user enters 2 i want "c" ti be displayed.. ive been messing about with more code but just cannot seem to get it working.

Comment: Thomas K >> I've tried that but the error that appears is ''TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str''

Comment: ask the person who has written the first 6 lines of the program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try converting `Number` to an integer first:

```
i = int(Number)                                                                 
print "You selected:", List[i]
```

Incidentally, it's good Python style to make variables lower case, and keep identifiers that begin with a capital letter for classes.  So, instead of `List` you could use `my_list` and instead of `Number` just use `number`.  (You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name since that will hide the built-in `list` type.)

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ["a", "b", "c"]
ii = raw_input("Please select a number: ")
print l[ii]
```

Comment: Only thing to remember here is that indexing starts from 0, not 1

Comment: The error that appears is 'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str' when i do that Jim

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do is called "indexing" a string. It is achieved as follows

```
letter_at_index = my_list[index]
```

Note that indices start from 0, that is,

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a = my_list[0]
b = my_list[1]
c = my_list[2]
```

Negative indices can be specified as well, for example

```
c = my_list[-1]
```

More info under Sequence Types [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
List = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
print "The list has the following", len(List), "list:", List
try:
    Number = raw_input ("Please select a number: ")
    item = List[int(Number)]
    print "The list item at", Number, "is", item
except EOFError:
    print "Error.  Nothing entered"
except ValueError:
    print "Error.  Expecting a number instead of:", Number
except IndexError:
    print "Error.  Number out of range:", Number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

print "The list has the following length: "+str( len(List))+ "\n list:"+repr( List)

List.append(raw_input("\nWhich item would you like to add? "))

print "\nThe list has the following length: "+str( len(List))+ "\n list:"+repr( List)

print '\nThe item at the position you entered is : '+\
      repr(List[int(raw_input ("\nPlease select a number: "))])[1:-1]
```

Result

```
The list has the following length: 6
 list:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

Which item would you like to add? (12,52,145)

The list has the following length: 7
 list:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '(12,52,145)']

Please select a number: 6

The item at the position you entered is : (12,52,145)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
i = None
listend = len(List)-1
while i == None:
    try:
        print ''
        raw = raw_input("Which item would you like to add? ")
        i = int(raw)
        value = List[i]
    except IndexError:
        print i, 'is out of bounds. Expecting an integer from 0 to', listend 
        i = None
    except:
        print 'You entered "%s" however I was expecting an integer from 0 to %s'%(raw, listend)
    else:
        print 'Result:', List[i]
```

It is often useful to loop while waiting for acceptable input in this way - you will notice that `i` is only set to something other than `None`  if `int(raw)` runs successfully, and if it is out of your list's bounds you set it back to `None`. The `else` statement is not strictly necessary as its content could go outside of the `while` loop, however it seem to be the situation it was designed for - running a block of code only if the try block has not thrown an exception, while not handling exceptions itself.